# XPages checkboxgroup and jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-mobile, xpages

If I use a checkboxgroup with jQuery Mobile I get some strange UI generated.
I thought I might workaround this by using a single checkbox inside a repeat control. I can get the UI to display correctly using this method and the repeat is bound to a view that I can use to generate the labels for each of the check boxes.

But I'm not sure how I should handle the data server side or what I should bind the check boxes to. Ultimately the selected values should be stored in a single, multi-value field on the Notes document. If I bind to this field on the document, then it just gets the value of the last checkbox - which makes sense.

Alternatively....is there some sort of fix to get the checkboxgroup to display correctly.

Have had this problem for a while...but it is now becoming a more urgent issue... so any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin - checkboxgroups suck in general. I suggest you use individual checkboxes and compute your desired answer on the back end. No issues with individual checkboxes

```
<xp:checkBox id="checkBox1" value="#{invite.Marketing}">
</xp:checkBox>
<xp:label value="Marketing" id="label4" for="checkBox1"
        style="font-weight:bold">
</xp:label>
<xp:checkBox id="checkBox2" value="#{invite.Tracking}">
</xp:checkBox>
<xp:label value="Tracking" id="label3" for="checkBox2"
        style="font-weight:bold">
</xp:label>
```

Comment: Hi Mark - Thanks for your speedy response as usual :-)

Comment: Hi Mark - Thanks for your speedy response as usual :-)  The example in the screenshot was a simple one. I have another instance with ~20 checkboxes required. The values are user-driven via some config docs. In your example code the individual checkboxes are bound to separate fields on the document. So where I have these 20 values that are dynamically generated within the repeat control what would I bind these to? Can I bind to dynamically generated field names?

Comment: Martin - not sure about dynamic binding.....I doubt it - try this then. Create the checkboxes as straight HTML without doing xp: checkbox. Then in your onsubmit collate them as a concatenated comma delimited string, stick them in a hidden field which IS bound to a field on the document. That field will then act as the capture point for your selected config documents. The XPage will allow submission of fields it does not recognize, it will just ignore them.

Comment: Mark - I went with your original suggestion using xp:checkbox controls. It is possible to have dynamic binding based on this post from Tim Tripcony http://bit.ly/IUr1d5 - episode 22 of XPages101 also helped with understanding how to pass a data source into the custom control. So once I have the checkbox values I can manipulate the data in the querySaveDocument event to set the fields on the doc  as required. Thx again!